# Apache Ignite RemoteListen .Net

Tags: .net, ignite

I started a Server through the BAT file, and then started a Client to write data through the code, and set the expiration time. Then I want to track expired entries on Client side by subscribing to `EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_EXPIRED`, but I look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-1682 - `RemoteListen` has been removed from Ignite.NET, what is the alternative plan? Or are there any examples to look at.

Comment: Please clarify - what do you intend to do? `Then I want to by subscribing to the remote Server is event date` - what does this mean?

Comment: I want to know when cached data expires by subscribing to remote server events, and add my own logic when the data expires.

Comment: I want to know when the cached data is expired by subscribing to server-side events (EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_EXPIRED), but right now the.NET API has LocalListen, not RemoteListen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LocalListen` on the server node, and then use Ignite Messaging to notify clients about the event.

**Server**

```cs
server.GetEvents().LocalListen(new EventListener(server.GetMessaging()), EventType.CacheObjectExpired);

...

public class EventListener  : IEventListener<CacheEvent>
{
    private readonly IMessaging _messaging;

    public EventListener(IMessaging messaging)
    {
        _messaging = messaging;
    }

    public bool Invoke(CacheEvent evt)
    {
        _messaging.Send(evt.Key, "Expired");

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
client.GetMessaging().LocalListen(new MessageListener(), "Expired");

...

public class MessageListener : IMessageListener<object>
{
    public bool Invoke(Guid nodeId, object message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Expired: " + message);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried the code you sent, but when the cache expired, there was still no message notification. Now I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: `codeCacheConfiguration configuration = new CacheConfiguration(CacheName, query);
var cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<string, Person>(configuration).WithExpiryPolicy(expiryPolicy);

var remotes = ignite.GetCluster().ForRemotes();
remotes.GetEvents().LocalListen(new EventListener(remotes.GetMessaging()), EventType.CacheObjectExpired);

var local = ignite.GetCluster().ForLocal().GetMessaging();
local.LocalListen(new MessageListener(), "Expired");`

Comment: @coder-yp here is a working gist: https://gist.github.com/ptupitsyn/42e6e6c3b20147d04f0f1bda9e1e1464

It starts both Client and Server in one process for simplicity, you can split them as you like.

Comment: Sorry, the link won't open

Comment: The link is public and it works. Can you reach github.com?

Comment: many thanks.I would like to ask a question, will the RemoteListen method be added to the.NET API in the future?I see this method in the code, but it is removed by adding an attribute (`ExcludeFromCodeCoverage`).

Comment: What is the plan for this.net RemoteListen API?We won't provide this method in the future but there will be other ways to implement it?